# No attribute getstatusoutput

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to ping a server using python subprocess but get the following error -

```
>>> import subprocess as sp
>>> sp.getstatusoutput('ping 127.0.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getstatusoutput'
```

Comment: Well, yes, [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) doesn't have that attribute. What were you expecting?

Answer (score 5):

[`subprocess.getstatusoutput()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.getstatusoutput) is only available in Python 3.x.

For Python 2.x, use the [`commands` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html#commands.getstatusoutput).

By the way, note that `getstatusoutput()` is equivalent to [`check_output(..., universal_newlines=True, stderr=STDOUT)`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) (available in both Python 2.x and 3.x).